# How to fill the whole canvas with specific color?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

How to fill the whole HTML5 `<canvas>` with one color.

I saw some solutions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20488590/set-backgroundcolor-styles-and-opacity-to-html5-canvas) to change the background color using CSS but this is not a good solution since the canvas remains transparent, the only thing that changes is the color of the space it occupies.

Another one is by creating something with the color inside the canvas, for example, a rectangle([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11702650/html5-canvas-how-to-fill-a-specific-context)) but it still does not fill the whole canvas with the color (in case the canvas is bigger than the shape we created).

Is there a solution to fill the whole canvas with a specific color?

Answer (score 268, accepted):

Yes, fill in a Rectangle with a solid color across the canvas, use the `height` and `width` of the canvas itself:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

```css
canvas{ border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<canvas width=300 height=150 id="canvas">
```

Comment: ``ctx.fillStyle="rgb(0,0,255)"`` [fillStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillStyle)

Answer (score 40):

If you want to do the background *explicitly*, you must be certain that you draw *behind* the current elements on the canvas.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
// Add behind elements.
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over'
// Now draw!
ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

Comment: Thank you for realizing people may not just want a block of color as an image!

Comment: This should actually be `destination-under`, and it should be the first operation on the canvas.

Comment: @Ciprian: If you use 'destination-over' it does not need to be the first operation. That mode specifies that the destination (the current content of the canvas) will be over the content of what you will draw.

Comment: @awe I trust you. My experience with Canvas is limited :)

Answer (score 23):

You can change the background of the canvas by doing this:

```html
<head>
    <style>
        canvas {
            background-color: blue;
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

Comment: @Enve said that he or she wanted it to not be using CSS.

Comment: Not useful for OP. But perhaps useful for people searching for the question in the title.

Comment: Nice exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: This one appars blue, but after saving the canvas as png by toDataURL, background appears transparent.

Answer (score 8):

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
canvas.setAttribute('width', window.innerWidth);
canvas.setAttribute('height', window.innerHeight);
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

//Draw Canvas Fill mode
ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
body { overflow: hidden; }
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
```

Answer (score 5):

We don't need to access the canvas context.

Implementing [hednek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50052052/10450752) in pure JS you would get `canvas.setAttribute('style', 'background-color:#00F8')`.  But my preferred method requires converting the *kabab-case* to *camelCase*.

> `canvas.style.backgroundColor = '#00F8'`

Comment: Adding Shapes Dynamically can have problem to show with this approach

Answer (score -1):

You know what, there is an entire library for canvas graphics. It is called p5.js
You can add it with just a single line in your head element and an additional sketch.js file.

Do this to your html and body tags first:

```html
<html style="margin:0 ; padding:0">
<body style="margin:0 ; padding:0">
```

Add this to your head:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.1/p5.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="sketch.js"></script>
```

**The sketch.js file**

```js
function setup() {
    createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    background(r, g, b);
}
```

Comment: Note that `p5.js` is `340kB` minizied _and_ gzipped! I'd say this page contains some slightly more  lightweight options..

Comment: @kano I wrote this answer when I was just a noob. It's been a long time since.