# Three divs side by side causing problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

So, what I ultimately want to achieve is this:

https://s17.postimg.org/7zkpt511r/imgdivs.png

what I have so far:

```
<style type="text/css">
.wrapper{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.left{
  float: left;
  background: silver;
  height: 100%;
}
.right{
 background: silver;
  float: right;
  height: 100%;
}
canvas{
position: absolute;
height: 100%;
}
</style>


<div class = "wrapper">
  <div class = "left"></div>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  <div class = "right">
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var WIDTH = 200; //could be anything, comes from previous calculations
$('#canvas').css("width", WIDTH);
$('#canvas').css("left", (window.innerWidth - WIDTH) / 2);
$('.left').css("width", (window.innerWidth - WIDTH) / 2);
$('.right').css("width", (window.innerWidth - WIDTH) / 2);

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, window.innerHeight);

</script>
```

So a little explanation, the canvas in the middle is dynamic in it's width(calculated with javascript) and pre-decided with it's height(100%), it is placed in the middle of the page, and the two divs to it's sides should stretch accordingly and equally and fill the rest of the page. I have many problems in my code; the divs sometimes overflow one below another, the canvas for some reason doesn't fillStyle it's whole dimension and so on.

I am afraid to try to do it in flexbox since old browsers do not support it properly, and I need all browsers support. Thank you for your time.

Comment: To get proper fill use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27736288/how-to-fill-the-whole-canvas-with-specific-color I've removed floats and position:absolute from canvas since you don't need it (placed all in css table): https://jsfiddle.net/zd75wq2e/3/

Answer (score 0):

To get the div height to work you need to add this to your css

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying in [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Kamae/q3ox11dh/5/) and I get a working solution. I added a `float:left;` to the wrapper and I removed all the `height: 100%;` because they're ignored by the browser. I just set the height according to the `window` element using JS.

I removed as well the `position: absolute;` on the `canvas` because is not needed to do what you need. Anyway if you need it for other purposes, my suggestion is then insert the `canvas` inside a `div class="center"` (for example) and apply the position absolute to the canvas inside that div.

Finally I added as well a `$(document).ready(function(){ ... });` to ensure the JS code is executed when the page is completely loaded.

**EDIT:** The `div`s calculation is made using `width: calc(50% - canvasWidth/2);`,this way it is working as well when you resize the window. But I thing the most important thing is working using `WIDTH` is producing your error, but getting the `$("#canvas").outerWidth()` is working fine...

Comment: It overflows in my browser, see evidence: https://s21.postimg.org/xn6in6i9j/51x.png

Comment: WTF... Sorry it wasn't in mine O.o This means is some weird random thing, let me try to figure it out

Comment: The only thing is if the px of the `window` element are odd, then you can see a px separation between `canvas` and `divs`... but I'm still improving it.

Comment: Please check it now, I simplified the code and it seems to be working, at least in my Chrome and IE11. I eddited as well my post

Answer (score 0):

Dont use position:absolute's it is not a good pratice for layouts

You can consider using display:flex for the same and consider using viewport width and height vw/vh

When you give your div width 100% and height 100% nothing gets effected to make it work you have to set html,body{width:100%,height:100%} which is not a good practice ,instead you can use vw/vh

check this snippet

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
}
.left {
  border-right: 1px solid;
  background: silver;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
}
.right {
  background: silver;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  border-left: 1px solid;
}
canvas {
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  <div class="right">
  </div>
```

Solution without display:flex

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
}
.left {
  border-right: 1px solid;
  background: silver;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
.right {
  background: silver;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  border-left: 1px solid;
  float: right;
}
canvas {
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  <div class="right">
  </div>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Hey, the canvas width should come within javascript not css since it can vary from anything to anything, secondly there is a weird problem when I fill with color the entire canvas with your code(white spot): https://s16.postimg.org/6auq89sj9/53x.png

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
body {
  margin:0;
  height:100vh;
}
.wrapper{
 display:table;

  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
 background-color:pink;
}
.left{
 display:table-cell;
  background-color: gray;
  height: 100%;

}
.right{
 background-color: blue;
display:table-cell;
  height: 100%;

}
canvas{
display:table-cell;
height: 100%;
}
```

JS:

```
var WIDTH = 234; //could be anything, comes from previous calculations
$('#canvas').css("width", WIDTH+'px');
$('.left').css("width", (window.innerWidth - WIDTH) / 2+'px');
$('.right').css("width", (window.innerWidth - WIDTH) / 2+'px');


var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/zd75wq2e/4/

So, basically, you was close. I've removed absolute positioning and floats, and i've rather used css table. I hope it has good support in older browsers, too. And, yes, as mentioned in comment, fill problem is solved in last line of js.

Comment: It seem to work on modern browsers... but the ones who have KitKat and jellyBean display it poorly.

Comment: @user7182273, for older mobile browsers, you can try with floats. But add  float to canvas div, too, rather than absolute positioning...