# How to set initial stage color in Konva?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, konvajs

I'm just starting with Konva and I wonder if there is a way to set the stage color? It is some kind of bright grey by default and I would like to change that, if possible, without having to add a rectangle and fill it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Konvajs is an implementation of functions on top of the standard HTML5 canvas.

If you google *html5 canvas background* color you will find many hits including for example   [how-to-fill-the-whole-canvas-with-specific-color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27736288/how-to-fill-the-whole-canvas-with-specific-color) on SO. The summary is:

- html5 canvas is transparent
- either set the colour on the host element via CSS,
- or generate a rectangle shape on its own layer with the rectangle dimensions filling the canvas.

Here is an example of using the CSS colour on the container div to colour the stage. I also added a stage rectangle which you could use instead by adding a fill colour to its definition. The stage rectangle is listening for clicks and has a click handler so that you can confirm it covers the entire stage area. The stage has a contentClick() listener that should be used with care because bubbling cannot be stopped.

```js
var width = window.innerWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight;


var rectButtonClicked  = false;

var stage = new Konva.Stage({
  container: 'container',
  width: width,
  height: height
});

var layer = new Konva.Layer();
stage.add(layer);

var stageRect =  new Konva.Rect({ 
  x:0,
  y:0,
  width: width,
  height: height,
  listening: true  // listen for clicks on the stage rectangle
})
layer.add(stageRect);

stageRect.on('click', function() {
  console.log('Stage click');
});

stageRect.draw(); // draw so we can see canvas rect.
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/konvajs/konva/1.7.6/konva.min.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="background-color: gold;"></div>
```