# PNG image with transparent background giving black background on canvas with drawImage and putImageData

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, canvas

I'm uploading the function here

```js
const createImage = (url) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const image = new Image();
    image.addEventListener("load", () => resolve(image));
    image.addEventListener("error", (error) => reject(error));
    image.setAttribute("crossOrigin", "anonymous");
    image.src = url;
  });

function getRadianAngle(degreeValue) {
  return (degreeValue * Math.PI) / 180;
}

export default async function getCroppedImg(imageSrc, pixelCrop, rotation = 0) {
  const image = await createImage(imageSrc);
  const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  const maxSize = Math.max(image.width, image.height);
  const safeArea = 2 * ((maxSize / 2) * Math.sqrt(2));

  canvas.width = safeArea;
  canvas.height = safeArea;

  ctx.translate(safeArea / 2, safeArea / 2);
  ctx.rotate(getRadianAngle(rotation));
  ctx.translate(-safeArea / 2, -safeArea / 2);

  ctx.drawImage(
    image,
    safeArea / 2 - image.width * 0.5,
    safeArea / 2 - image.height * 0.5
  );

  const data = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, safeArea, safeArea);

  canvas.width = pixelCrop.width;
  canvas.height = pixelCrop.height;

  ctx.putImageData(
    data,
    0 - safeArea / 2 + image.width * 0.5 - pixelCrop.x,
    0 - safeArea / 2 + image.height * 0.5 - pixelCrop.y
  );
  return canvas;
}
```

This is the original image:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1r5fHjYswsG89OkViN6-9EmmLP8BnojE5/view?usp=sharing

This is the image after this function is called:
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ekko-development.appspot.com/o/dor3m3%2FYDW9hT0nJjhaP7uOoCpFO2Jzd6B3%2Fsocial%2Fimages_gallery%2Fbe1014?alt=media&token=8b30521f-196b-4c1b-a5b5-aea3d6e1f898

Comment: What's the expected output? In this case `putImageData` is applying the image on top of the default background which is black. If you want to match the background pattern seen in the first image, then you would have to literally draw it to the canvas before doing rest of the work.

Comment: I tried changing the background color using fill style method, and also by dom manipulating  the canvas. but this isnt working. I just want to change the color to white

Comment: Ah, check here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27736313/228885 .